# Route guard method breaking routing

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

Edit: [StackBlitz minimal repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-routes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fguard.ts) seems to work, so there's something else amiss it seems..

Angular 6.1.3

I have a route that needs to be guarded based on the param `slug`.

```js
{
  path: 'market/:slug',
  component: MarketComponent,
  canActivate: [RoleGuard],
},
```

RoleGuard `canActivate` method:

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  const market$ = this.marketService.getBySlug(
    route.paramMap.get('slug')
  ); // returns an observable of the corresponding market object

  // Verify the user is authorized to see this market.
  return this.authService.isAuthorized(market);
}
```

authService.isAuthorized:

```js
isAuthorized(market: Observable<Market>): Observable<boolean> {
  return combineLatest(this.user$, market).pipe(
    map(([user, market]) => {
      // Check roles of the user based on the market's configuration
      return true;
    })
  );
}
```

I've removed the user/market logic just trying to strip out anything that could be causing problems, but when I return the above method inside `canActivate` the routing stops.  Route trace:

```js
Router Event: NavigationStart
NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/market/sams-corner-store')
NavigationStart {id: 2, url: "/market/sams-corner-store", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}

Router Event: RoutesRecognized
RoutesRecognized(id: 2, url: '/market/sams-corner-store', urlAfterRedirects: '/market/sams-corner-store', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'market/sams-corner-store', path:'market/:slug') } )
RoutesRecognized {id: 2, url: "/market/sams-corner-store", urlAfterRedirects: "/market/sams-corner-store", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
GuardsCheckStart(id: 2, url: '/market/sams-corner-store', urlAfterRedirects: '/market/sams-corner-store', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'market/sams-corner-store', path:'market/:slug') } )
GuardsCheckStart {id: 2, url: "/market/sams-corner-store", urlAfterRedirects: "/market/sams-corner-store", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: ChildActivationStart
ChildActivationStart(path: '')
ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}

Router Event: ActivationStart
ActivationStart(path: 'market/:slug')
ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
```

During normal routing more Router events are triggered, but here it just stops.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the `isAuthorized` not emitting anything, but I'm stumped.  After the failure, navigating anywhere doesn't do anything; the URL stays the same and nothing else is logged to the console.

At times the method isn't even called, console.log isn't called in the `combineLatest`/`withLatestFrom`.

I've tried `combineLatest` and `withLatestFrom` with some operator variants to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

canActivate guard will subscribe on returned Observable and waiting till that Observable is completed, until that moment no other router event will be handled.
Add `first()` (Rx operator) to the user$ and market$ Observable.
PS instead of `combineLatest` use `forkJoin`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on the router events.  I think something's a bit off in my implementation but in trying to zero-in on the issue this has helped.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right, but a guard requires the observable to complete.
So you are stuck waiting for it.

try doing

```
return this.authService.isAuthorized(market).pipe(
    take(1)
);
```

this will take the first result and complete, which should fix your problem.

Comment: As in the above comment something's off in my code, but in other tests `take` helps out, thanks!